# Get the original order of the array when using BOTH filter with find

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter, find

I have two array's of objects.

a) **this.units** (holds ALL the info on the units)

b) **item.units** (holds just the IDs of the units being used)

I am trying to match up the full unit with the unit id. The method below works but it puts the units out of their original order.

The **item.unit** will have an array of unit ids in a specific order lets say 1,2,3,4

I then need to attach the full unit from **this.units** to the **item.unit** but keep the same order 1,2,3,4

This code matches the full unit to the item unit but it uses the order from **this.units** not **item.unit** so the end results is something like 4,2,1,3

```
previewSectionInfo(item) {
    const sectionsUnits = this.units.filter((u) => {
        return item.units.find(el => el.id == u.id)
    })
    item.units = sectionsUnits 
}
```

Comment: I think I would instead `map()` over `item.unit` and return the corresponding record from `this.units`.

Comment: @mykaf make it an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would instead `map()` over `item.unit` (keeping its order) and return the corresponding record from `this.units`.

```js
const item = {};
item.units = [1,3,5];

//const thiss = {};
this.units = [
  {id:1,name:"one"},
  {id:2,name:"two"},
  {id:3,name:"three"},
  {id:4,name:"four"},
  {id:5,name:"five"}
 ];

function previewSectionInfo() {
  const specificUnits = item.units.map(
    function(unitID){
      return this.units.find(el => el.id == unitID);
    }
  ) 
  console.log(specificUnits);
}

previewSectionInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer. For anyone else out there having this problem here is what I now have:

```
const sectionsUnits = item.units.map(p => {
    return Object.assign(...this.units.filter(i => i.id == p.id))
})
```